# Sending Outlook Email with embedded image using VBS

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, html-email, outlook-2007

I am currently using the following VBS script to send an email and it works fine, however the image is sent as an attachment.  I would instead like to embed the image into the email.  I understand that I must reference the attachment in the HTML body of the email but I am struggling to do this.

Any suggestions?

```
Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim ol, ns, newMail
MyTime = Now

ToAddress = "email@address.com"
MessageSubject = "Auto Stats " & MyTime
MessageBody = "Stats Attached" & vbCrLf & "Produced at " & MyTime
MessageAttachment = "P:\stats.png"
Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment)
newMail.Send
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the code below

```
Const PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E"
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"


Sub testing2()
Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim ol, ns, newMail
Dim realAttachment
MyTime = Now

ToAddress = "testing@address.com"
MessageSubject = "Auto Stats " & MyTime
MessageBody = "Stats Attached" & vbCrLf & "Produced at " & MyTime
MessageAttachment = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg"
Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody
newMail.Recipients.Add (ToAddress)
Set realAttachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment)
Set oPA = realAttachment.PropertyAccessor
oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG, "image/jpeg"
oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "myident" 'change myident for another other image
newMail.HTMLBody = newMail.HTMLBody & "<IMG align=baseline border=0 hspace=0 src=cid:myident>" 'need to match the "myident" above
newMail.Send
End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in outlook 2003 and 2016

```
    'I do have a solution, and that is to convert the Body to HTML
Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim ol, ns, newMail
MyTime = Now

ToAddress = "email@address.com"
MessageSubject = "Auto Stats " & MyTime
' The trick is to convert all the message body into HTML
' Don't mix script text and HTML. Then simply add an HTML image reference.
' Remember if the recipient can't get to the image
' it won't appear in the email body, and will be blank. So don't use a local image. 
' Use an recipient reachable image.
MessageBody = "<html>Stats Attached" & "<p>Produced at  " & MyTime & _
      "<p><img src=""http://somedomain.com/.../stats.png""></html><br>"
'MessageAttachment = "P:\stats.png" ! Now Uneccessary 
Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.htmlBody = MessageBody 'Changed the newmMail.Body to newMail.htmlBody
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
'newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment) !This was removed because it would just appear as email attachment
newMail.Display
```

Comment: Th OP wanted an embedded image attachment. Your code refers to an image on a remote web server.