# Outlook Addin Getting Attachments not Pictures in Mail

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

I am having an issue with an AddIn I am building.

I want to get only the ATTACHMENT appended to a mail.

However :

Mail.Attachment also includes the pictures or logos in the mail content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check out the following Extended MAPI properties, use [PropertyAccessor.GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868350.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for that:

- PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, DASL name: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"
- PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN, DASL name: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

Take a look at the similar question - [Distinguish visible and invisible attachments with Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310925/distinguish-visible-and-invisible-attachments-with-outlook-vba) for more informaton and sample code.

Comment: Some attachments always have the MIME content id, in particular messages from Lotus Notes always have that header.
 The real test is to check the HTMLBody property and see if any attachments are actually referenced by the img tags.