# Outlook, I want to move messages with an attachment but it also moves messages without attachments

Tags: outlook

I'm using numerous rules to stop cluttering my inbox, and one of them is moving emails which contain attachments.

I want to move all emails which contain attachments to an 'attachments' folder. This works, but it also seems to move emails which don't have any attachments (at least the little paperclip logo doesn't show up).

Any idea what is going on?

EDIT: I found out that emails which didn't have attachments, still have the following in the header.

```
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
```

I think this is because of the signatures containing some pictures and links. Any way to exclude these?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinguish visible and invisible attachments with Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310925/distinguish-visible-and-invisible-attachments-with-outlook-vba)

Answer (score 1):

No, embedded image attachments are still regular by-value attachments. 
On the low level, you could exclude messages with a specific MAPI property set (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B`, aka HidePaperClip), but the rule wizard won't let you specify a MAPI property.

Answer (score 0):

Closest I've been able to do is have the rule use an exception that searches for the image filetypes in the body of the e-mail. E.g. if you have the rule exception search for ".png" and ".jpg", e-mails with those filetypes will be excluded. However, this will also exclude e-mails with both attachments and embedded images, since outlook rules can't distinguish between the two.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310925/distinguish-visible-and-invisible-attachments-with-outlook-vba