# VBA or Outlook Options - Automatic image compression under outlook (in annex or in message body)

Tags: vba, image, outlook, image-compression

I'm looking for a way to automatically compress pictures in a message in Outlook when it is sent.
These pictures can be attachments or are in the html message body.

The way i found is for attachement by passing in "File" then an option like Resize the pictures (don't know the name of option in english)
=> I would like this option is by default enabled to avoid to forget to enable this

On the other way, if i have some picture inside the body message, i can use the button "compress pictures" for all the pictures in the message but once again i would like it was by default.

Have you got any idea to perform this with the outlook options or by VBA?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find images used in the message body attached to Outlook items. In the `HTMLBody` property value you can meet the following entries for such images:

```
"<IMG src =""cid:Filename"">"
```

On the attachment you can find the "cid:" value set up using the following property:

```
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"
```

The [PropertyAccessor.GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.getproperty) method can be use to retrieve the property value (on the attachment).

Finally, after detecting embedded images the [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method which saves the attachment to the specified path can be used. On the disk you can make all the required modifications and then re-attach the file anew (after deleting the source).

Comment: Have you got an example? WHat about the picture in attachement?

Comment: You may try searching over the internet for the sample code, for example, take a look at [Distinguish visible and invisible attachments with Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310925/distinguish-visible-and-invisible-attachments-with-outlook-vba)