# OUTLOOK VBA REPLY ALL With attachments but without pictures from the email body

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using the code below to reply all with attachments but it is also including pictures that are in the body of the email as attachments. I'd like to avoid this to happen and only include the original files as attachments. is there a way to do this ?

thanks

```
Sub ReplyAllWithAttachments()
    Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oItem As Object
     
    Set oItem = GetCurrentItem()
    If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
        Set oReply = oItem.replyall
        CopyAttachments oItem, oReply
        oReply.Display
        oItem.UnRead = False
    End If
     
    Set oReply = Nothing
    Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
         
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
     
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function

Sub CopyAttachments(objSourceItem, objTargetItem)
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set fldTemp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
   strPath = fldTemp.Path & "\"
   For Each objAtt In objSourceItem.Attachments
      strFile = strPath & objAtt.FileName
      objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
      objTargetItem.Attachments.Add strFile, , , objAtt.DisplayName
      fso.DeleteFile strFile
   Next

   Set fldTemp = Nothing
   Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinguish visible and invisible attachments with Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310925/distinguish-visible-and-invisible-attachments-with-outlook-vba)